# How can I download a file from firebase storage in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, download, firebase-storage

I want to download a file from my firebase storage with the download url provided.
Instead the tag
"<a href={'file url'} download={'name'}>download"
opens the file in the browser instead of downloading it from firebase storage.

I have tried leaving the download attribute without a value! I expected it to download like it does for a file from the local source (the project directory). but the firebase download URL opens the file in the browser instead of downloading it from firebase storage on a device.

Comment: But basically a file link in the browser enables the user to download the file from the browser. i.e on chrome, the top right corner has the download button for the user to download the file.
I'd say however the reason why it is not automatically doing so, without looking at your code, is that when you save your files to firebase storage, you are not including the file extension in the filename, and when you get the downloadURL from firebase, the browser cannot recognize the type of file the link possesses. I'd suggest appending the file extension to the file url when downloading the file.

Comment: yeah thanks, I appended the URL with the file extension. but the file contains the URL instead of the uploaded file.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href={'file url'} download={'name'}>download</a>
```

Here in your code you're giving the link via the href attribute and then using the download attribute to make it a download link and then giving it a string.

The problem here is that the download attribute doesn't require any value but you gave it a string which is why it is not working.

To fix this, just make it:

```
<a href={'file url'} download>download</a>
```

Hope this helps :D

Comment: Thanks, but l later found a fix with an error.
i was able to download the file but there was a cross origin error